# How to use (.) instead of (,) as the grouping separator when displaying a number with String.Format?

Tags: c#, localization, numbers, string.format

I want to change change (,) to (.) when use String.Format in C#

String.Format("{0:0,0}",1000) -> 1,000

But I want: 1.000

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You do not want to replace "," with "." - you want a different NUMERiC format, which is somethihg different. Otherwise I would say"rewrite your format script".

Comment: @user2864740: i want "." represent a grouping separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that with

```
ToString(new CultureInfo("nl-NL"))
```

Basically any CultureInfo which fits your description.

Read up [here on CultureInfo - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I suspect we're looking at `vi-VN` .

Comment: `de-DE` is what you want!

Comment: `sl-SI` should be ok :)

Comment: You should use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo()` instead of creating a new one. It's faster and uses less memory because it uses a cached read-only copy of the corresponding `CultureInfo` object. (Don't use it if you want to modify the resulting object.)

Comment: @Pmleader: thank you so much, this short and easy to use or understand

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like this:

```
NumberFormatInfo newNumberFormat= (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
newNumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
string.Format(newNumberFormat,"{0:#,#}",1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with your number var:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
string myNumbreString = myNumber.ToString("0.00", nfi);
```